# How to do it like "with"(Pascal) in C programming?

Tags: c++, c, pascal

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does C++ have “with” keyword like Pascal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279180/does-c-have-with-keyword-like-pascal)
>   [Equivalent of with(from Pascal) to C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443716/equivalent-of-withfrom-pascal-to-c-c)

It's very convenient to use "with" in Pascal. And how can I do it in C/C++ programming?

The following from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29#Pointer_types) shows how the `with` keyword is used to avoid repeating the name of a record pointer when doing many accesses through it:

```
new(ptoNode);

...
with ptoNode^ do
begin
  a := 10;
  b := 'A';
  c := nil
end;
```

Comment: A better question might describe what you're after without depending on any other context. For instance, I haven't written any pascal code since the early 1990s. If you don't use it, you'll lose it. However, I may still be able to answer the question if you actually tell us the behaviour you want, instead of a different languages construct.

Comment: My Pascal is *very* rusty - can you explain what `with` does there?

Comment: You can't. (And it's a bad practice in Pascal, too, even if it's supported there. It leads to hard to track down scoping issues, and makes code harder to read and maintain.)

Comment: I edited the question to include an example of the `with` keyword, from Wikipedia.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2279180/929510

Comment: The question concerns this type of construct:  `MyObj := SomeObject.Create; with MyObj do begin SomeProperty := AVal; BVal := SomeFunc(AVal); end;`, where without the `with` it would be `MyObj.SomeProperty := AVal; BVal := MyObj.SomeFunc(AVal);`. It's a sort of shorthand acess to an object instance in a code block.

Comment: In the D programming language, which many software developers see as a modern C++ (and more), you have exactly what you have in Pascal - the with statement. I would say that D's version of the `with` statement is even better as it takes care of three use-cases. More about it here - http://www.dlang.org/statement.html#WithStatement .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must, get yourself a helper (pointer) object and "reduce"

```
some_complicated_expression->a = 0;
some_complicated_expression->b = 42;
```

to

```
{ /* new block to delimit scope of `tmp` */
    whatever *tmp = some_complicated_expression;
    tmp->a = 0;
    tmp->b = 42;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it in C. And I'd say that in C++ as well (though maybe there are some inhumane template metaprogramming experiments :-) )

Comment: Ohh... you make me want to try with some trick based on the ternary operator (see http://www.artima.com/cppsource/foreach.html )

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can't since there is no such functionality. You simply have to repeat the pointer name.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `structs` :  see this : [Equivalent of with(from Pascal) to C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443716/equivalent-of-withfrom-pascal-to-c-c)

And this : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Pascal_and_C

Comment: After reading that other question, how do you conclude that the answer is structs? The only place that word even appears is in the question *tag*. That means it's a question *about* structs.

Comment: And the second link only provides: "There is no equivalent feature to `with` in C."  Which would have been shorter to type than the link text!!  This answer is so bizarre...

Answer (score 0):

In C, I don't think you can do it.

As long as you're not trying to code Pascal in C++ though you can just use objects which will have the same effect. Call a member on the object that does the work you want and voila, the extra `ptr->` goes away for each step done by the object's method!